# Lake Formation Cross-Account Share, Issues seeing database in external account

Tags: amazon-web-services, data-lake, aws-lake-formation, data-mesh

I have shared a database called ingest between account A (Source) and account B (Target). Once shared I went on Resource Access Manager on account B and accepted the share request. I can now see the database on Lake Formation (Console) under Permissions -> Data lake permissions, but for some reason I cannot see it listed under databases. When I click the database name on Permissions -> Data lake permissions, I get an access denied error saying I don't have "glue:GetDatabase on resource: ###########" but I am using an admin account and when trying using IAM Access Simulator I get no problem. Does anyone have an Idea of what might be the issue here?

Thank you for your help :)

tried the IAM access simulator, refreshing the screen, removing cache. I have granted access in the Source Account to the target account with "Super" permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, I did not remove the IAMAllowedPrincipals on the source accounts database. Once removing this I was able to see and query the database and its associated tables.

Answer (score -1):

looks like lakeformation admin issue. Did you tried adding your admin account as lakeformation admin